# I want to save and restore a mutableList or array in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, mutable

I have the following mutableList

```
val rowsSavedList = mutableListOf<Int>()

The data is lost when the app changes from portrait to landscape. I save the rest of my data using onSaveInstanceState and restore with onRestoreInstanceState Is there a way to do this with the mutableList.
```

I have tried using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState but it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put it in a `ViewModel` when you want your states to persist through configuration changes, like in your case a rotation.

Comment: most standard implementations of list are Serializable, you can use one of those (e.g ArrayList). Also ensure that each element in your list is also Serializable.

Comment: Ok thanks, ViewModel sounds just what I need. I have never used it so far. Is it possible to convert my array of Int's (rowsSavedList) to a ViewModel and then still be able to access the array data after screen rotation. Are you able to show me code needed.  Cheers

Comment: You cannot convert an array to a viewModel, you might find a way to use a view model here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-viewmodel#0

Comment: Use a ViewModel to display the data, so it doesnt affected by the activity lifecycle events